# Why helium and not hydrogen the first atom to form in early universe?

Tags: electrons, universe, atoms

I was reading scientific american magazine to learn about formation of first atom and surprisingly it is helium, a noble gas... what are the electrons thinking? Actually wait what are the protons thinking, 2 protons together in helium nuclei forming first?

Comment: The atoms form when kT falls below the ionisation energy. This is long, long after nucleosynthesis so the protons and helium nuclei had been around for ages. Helium forms first because it has the higher ionisation enery.

Comment: @JohnRennie: I read some papers suggesting deuterium formed and survived long enough to become helium but never mention ionisation energy.

Comment: That SA article says: *The first “atoms” in the universe were not atoms at all—they were just nuclei that had not found electrons yet*, then *Of these three, helium was the first to begin forming “real” atoms. An atom is more than a nucleus—it must
also possess electrons. Helium nuclei were the first to gather a full purse of electrons en masse.* So the article is specifically referring to the neutralisation of the positive nuclei by the electrons around them. The nuclei with the largest ionisation energy will be neutralised first.